# Do you have to defend Fort Condor in the mini-game to get the Phoenix and Huge Materia?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

In the last battle for Fort Condor, you are able to get the Phoenix summon materia and a Huge materia.  Do you have to actually win the Fort Condor mini-game to get these?  Or, if you fail the mini-game but still defeat the boss triggered by failing, do you still get them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is No, you can obtain the materia by other means outside of Fort Condor. As far as winning it at Fort Condor, you can lose the mini-game, but must defeat the boss (CMD. Grandhorn) at the end of it.

**CAUTION: May contain spoilers for those wishing to figure this out on their own.**

From the Wiki:

> **Phoenix Materia is obtained at Fort Condor if Cid and the party manage to protect the Huge Materia inside from Shinra.** If they do
> so, the Condor sitting atop the fort dies and its baby hatches. During
> the condor's death the fiery wings of a Phoenix are seen, and
> afterwards a Phoenix Materia can be found lying on the floor near the
> nest.
>
> **If the player loses to the boss fought atop Fort Condor after failing the minigame
> to protect the fort, they will not obtain Phoenix, but it can still be dug from Bone
> Village after the event.**

If you miss out on the Phoenix materia at Fort Condor, here is how you can obtain it:

You can obtain it by digging at Bone Village from Location 4 on the map below.

[image: Location of Phoenix Materia at Bone Village]

More details can be found about Bone Village on the [FF7 wiki.](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Bone_Village?file=Bonevillagemap.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But if you lose the mini-game and win the boss battle, do you still get the Huge Materia?  Or do you HAVE to win the mini-game to get it?

Comment: @Jeff Just have to win the boss battle if I recall correctly

Comment: Halfwarr is correct. I'll edit my post to make this more clear.

Comment: @Jeff and fyi, if you can't be bothered to visit the place after every major story event, you can just give them some money to do the battles for you.